# Setting ComboBox.Cursor doesn't work for Default/Arrow cursors

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

In a Windows Form in C#, in the designer file, each of these will work fine:

```
this.someComboBox.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.AppStarting;
this.someComboBox.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Cross;
```

These don't though:

```
this.someComboBox.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Arrow;
this.someComboBox.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
```

Namely, when trying to use `Cursors.Arrow` or `Cursors.Default`, if you were to then move the mouse cursor over the textual part of the ComboBox, as opposed to the arrow over to the right, the cursor will be set to `Cursors.IBeam`, not an arrow.

*Why?  How do you force it to use an arrow instead (properly)?*

If it just did this for `Cursors.Default`, then maybe that just means the default cursor lets the control pull from a set of different defaults for different circumstances.  If it did it for all cursors, then it would seem that the property's name is misleading and that it should really be set somewhere else.  But it works just fine for the first two and fails for the other two.

In case it helps, this is the sort of code in the designer file and main file that is able to reproduce this problem:

```
// designer file:

this.someComboBox.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Arrow;
this.someComboBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.someComboBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(130, 73);
this.someComboBox.Name = "someComboBox";
this.someComboBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(128, 21);
this.someComboBox.TabIndex = 2;
this.someComboBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ComboBox_Click);
this.someComboBox.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(
        this.ComboBox_KeyPress);

//..........................................................................

// main file:

private void ComboBox_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ((ComboBox)(sender)).DroppedDown = true;
}

private void ComboBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

as well as a graphic of the ComboBox:

[image]

Comment: The textbox portion of the combobox forces its own cursor preference, an I-Beam like all textboxes use.  You would have to intercept the WM_SETCURSOR message by deriving your own class from ComboBox and overriding WndProc().  Rather best to not confuse the user.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks.  I tried essentially the following in the subclass, but it's still having a little bit of trouble unfortunately: `[SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)] protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {if (m.Msg != 0x0020 /*WM_SETCURSOR*/) {base.WndProc(ref m);}}` (I know that's bad for LSP, but I would change it for production code.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Create a new class inherited from ComboBox and add the Following code :

```
// To change de Cursor to Arrow, it is required to change DefaultCursor to another cursor thant the default Arrow.
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property DefaultCursor As Cursor = Cursors.Hand
Public Overrides Property Cursor As Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
```